# Mutual exclusion isn't exclusive

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I have the following code which runs in 2 threads started by an init call from the main thread. One for writing to a device, one for reading. My app is called by other threads to add items to the queues. `pop_queue` handles all locking, as does `push_queue`. Whenever I modify a `req r`, I lock it's mutex. `q->process` is a function pointer to one of either `write_sector`, `read_setor`. I need to guard against simultaneous calls to the two function pointers, so I'm using a mutex on the actual process call, however this is not working.

According to the text program, I am making parallel calls to the process functions. How is that possible given I lock immediatly before and unlock immediately afterwards?

The following error from `valgrind --tool=helgrind` might help?

```
==3850== Possible data race during read of size 4 at 0xbea57efc by thread #2
==3850==    at 0x804A290: request_handler (diskdriver.c:239)
```

Line 239 is `r->state = q->process(*device, &r->sd) +1`

```
void *
request_handler(void *arg)
{
    req *r;
    queue *q = arg;
    int writing = !strcmp(q->name, "write");
    for(;;) {
        /*
         * wait for a request
         */
        pop_queue(q, &r, TRUE);

        /*
         * handle request
         * req r is unattached to any lists, but must lock it's properties incase being redeemed
         */
        printf("Info: driver: (%s) handling req %d\n", q->name, r->id);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&r->lock);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&q->processing);
        r->state = q->process(*device, &r->sd) +1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->processing);

        /* 
         * if writing, return the SectorDescriptor
         */
         if (writing) {
            printf("Info: driver (write thread) has released a sector descriptor.\n");
            blocking_put_sd(*sd_store, r->sd);
            r->sd = NULL;
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&r->lock);
        pthread_cond_signal(&r->changed);

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the one other location where the req's properties are read

```
int redeem_voucher(Voucher v, SectorDescriptor *sd)
{
    int result;

    if (v == NULL){
        printf("Driver: null voucher redeemed!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    req *r = v;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&r->lock);

    /* if state = 0 job still running/queued */
    while(r->state==0) {
        printf("Driver: blocking for req %d to finish\n", r->id);
        pthread_cond_wait(&r->changed, &r->lock);
    }

    sd = &r->sd;
    result = r->state-1;
    r->sd = NULL;
    r->state = WAIT;
    //printf("Driver: req %d completed\n", r->id);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&r->lock);
    /*
     * return req to pool
     */    
    push_queue(&pool_q, r);
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT 2**
here's the push_ and pop_queue functions

```
int
pop_queue(struct queue *q, req **r, int block)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&q->lock);
    while(q->head == NULL) {
        if(block) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&q->wait, &q->lock);
        }
        else {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    req *got = q->head;
    q->head = got->next;
    got->next = NULL;
    if(!q->head) {
        /* just removed last element */
        q->tail = q->head;
    }

    *r = got;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);
    return TRUE;
}

/*
 * perform a standard linked list insertion to the queue specified
 * handles all required locking and signals any listeners
 * return: int - if insertion was successful
 */
int
push_queue(queue *q, req *r)
{
    /*
     * push never blocks, 
     */
    if(!r || !q)
        return FALSE;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&q->lock);

    if(q->tail) {
        q->tail->next = r;
        q->tail = r;
    }
    else {
        /* was an empty queue */
        q->tail = q->head = r;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);
    pthread_cond_signal(&q->wait);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the available information, it seems that a likely possibility then is that another thread is modifying the data pointed to by `*device`. Perhaps it is being modified while the `q->processing` mutex is not held.

Comment: According to the instructions, device will never change. So the problem must be with the ->sd data. However I'm told that this will not change either.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
pthread_cond_signal(&r->changed);
```

let me suspect that you have other code that is also manipulating the structure pointed to by `r`. In any case it makes not much sense if you have nobody waiting for that condition variable. (And you should invert the unlock and signal lines.)

So, probably your error is just somewhere else, where you access `r` simultaneaously without taking the lock on the mutex. You didn't show us the rest of your code, so saying more would be even more guess work.

Comment: Hi I added an edit to show the only other place where the req's properties are accessed.

Comment: @Jens: my understanding is that it's OK to call `pthread_cond_signal()` outside of the lock (but updating the checked variable needs to occur in the lock). Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Michael, both are valid. But the POSIX standard says "`however, if predictable scheduling behavior is required, then that mutex shall be locked by the thread calling ... pthread_cond_signal`"

Comment: @AlasdairC, what about `push_queue` and `pop_queue`?

Comment: @JensGustedt added them. but I doubt they're causing the problem

Comment: in `pop_queue` you manipulate `*got` without holding its mutex. You only hold the lock on the queue. Maybe this is ok, if you can prove that you don't have a race, but that would depend on how you use this code, I think. So better lock it there, too. If there is no congestion, taking a lock is not very expensive, so you wouldn't loose much.